# Unity: I need to edit my prefab but I can't move anything inside it!

Tags: unity, animation, prefabs

I imported a character into Unity and turned him into a prefab. I couldn't get my custom "Look-At" script to work for the eyes, which are children of the prefab I imported. So I opened the prefab and discovered (to my *HORROR*) that I am unable to transform his eyes AT ALL, even in the prefab-view. It's like his body parts are made of stone, or something! I checked his eyes in the Blender scene and don't see any animation data attached to them. So how could this happen? How can I fix it?

The eyes ARE children of a bone called "root", which I don't think has any keyframes in any animation. Further, all my bones imported as empties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click the sub-object in prefab-view, choose "Unpack Prefab".

I ask a lot of questions with simple solutions but I didn't find any other questions describing this kind of problem. I will keep this up in case somebody else is having the same problem.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as Accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this character is set up with an [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html). This animator controls the transforms of all the sub-objects, which is why you can't change those manually. It is recommended that you control this characters individual parts using the [animation system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html). But if you really don't want that, then you can find and remove the animator component. That should allow you to freely manipulate all the sub-objects.